# Flash Dynamic Text Width

Tags: flash, width, textfield

Hey! I try to find out the text size of a textfield in the following example

```
field.text = 'aaaaaaa';
trace(field.textWidth);

setTimeput(function(){
   field.text = 'aa';
   trace(field.textWidth);
},2000)
```

The number is always the same. Why?
I need the text width so I can adjust size for a background movieclip.
Thx!

Comment: the number is always the same - and wrong/zero?

Comment: Try setting the `autosize` to `left` and reading the text field's `width` instead.

Comment: it looks like I have a bug :)
thx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the [TextLineMetrics](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html) class.  It could get you close enough.  I've used it a few times and its accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a typo on line 4.  "setTimeput" instead of "setTimeout."